# sorting algorithm challenge using 'for of loop' instead of 'for loop' - issue

Tags: arrays, for-loop, for-of-loop

I have solved an algorithm using a for loop, but I have been trying to use a for of loop, to make it easier to read, but i'm not getting the same output when I used a traditional for loop?

```
const sortByHeight = (a)=>{

const array2 = a.filter(num => {
    if (num !== -1){
        return num
    }
}).sort((a,b) => a-b)

let indexVal = 0;

for ( let num of a){
     if(num !== -1 ){
         num = array2[indexVal]
         indexVal++
     }
 }


return a;

 //for loop does work
//     for ( let i=0; i < a.length; i++){
//     if(a[i] !== -1 ){
//         a[i] = array2[indexVal]
//         indexVal++
//     }
// }
// return a;
```

`console.log(sortByHeight([-1, 150, 190, 170, -1, -1, 160, 180]));`}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`num` is a local variable inside the loop. Assigning to it does *not* change the corresponding element in the array. This is similar to how assigning to a function parameter has no effect on the argument that was passed to the function.

Your best bet is just to stick to indexing the array like you were before. Use `for...of` when you want to iterate over an array and just *read* it. It doesn't allow for overwriting elements like you're trying to do though.

If you really wanted to use `for...of`, you could zip the array to be sorted with another array of indices so you can index when required, but you're losing any readability benefit of `for...of` at that point.